# How to use CGI request to Ghostscript

Tags: perl, cgi, ghostscript

I need to call Ghostscript in one of our cgi to convert a PDF file to a PNG image. This cgi has the encoded PDF stream in the request then decodes it, like

```
my $PDF_ENCODED = $q->param('PDF_ENCODED');
my $PDF_DECODED = decode_base64($PDF_ENCODED);
```

and it will generate a PNG image on the disk by calling 'gs' command.

My problem is I do not know how to pipe the $PDF_DECODED to gs command line. I have tried

```
system("$PDF_DECODED | gs -dNOPAUSE -q -r300 -sDEVICE=png16m -dBATCH -sOutputFile=/tmp/ghostscript/new-test.png-")
```

But it is not working.

Thanks.

Thanks again, golimar and simbabque.
It is working with

```
$SIG{PIPE} = 'IGNORE';
open(FH, "| gs -dNOPAUSE -q -r300 -sDEVICE=png16m -dBATCH -sOutputFile=/tmp/ghostscript/new-test.png -")  or die "can't fork: $!";
print FH "$PDF_DECODED\n"   or die "can't write: $!";
close FH            or die "can't close: status=$?";
```

Comment: An API to the Ghostscript library exists: http://p3rl.org/GSAPI, this is a bit more efficient and a bit less error-fraught than shelling out to the `gs` binary.

Comment: Thanks for the Ghostscript library, will check it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Perl you can open processes as if they were files, and when you write to the "file" handle, instead of writing data to a file, you are piping data to a process, see [*Using open() for IPC* in `perlipc`](http://p3rl.org/ipc#Using-open%28%29-for-IPC).

Comment: User200340: You need to do what golimar says because your `system` call doesn't like the binary that is your pdf file on the command line. This solution saves you the additional step of saving to a file first.